# Problems installing SSL Certificates on Node.JS server

Tags: node.js, ssl

I bought SSL Certificates from Godaddy for our website, with two web servers on the same AWS EC2 instance - Apache Tomcat and Node/Express.

After installing the SSL Certificates on both the web servers, https://example.com is opening (Apache), but the GET request from Apache to Node is failing.

The GET request to Node is working fine with the self-generated certificate (though it shows a crossed out https). When we replace that with CA certificates, it is not working. Please see the relevant code below.

```
    var https = require("https"); // https server core module
    var fs = require("fs"); // file system core module
    var express = require("express"); // web framework external module

// Setup and configure Express http server. Expect a subfolder called
“static” to be the web root.

    var httpApp = express();
    httpApp.configure(function() {
    httpApp.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static/"));
    });

    // Start Express https server on port 443
    var webServer = https.createServer(
    {
    key:  fs.readFileSync("/pathtokeys/ssl.private.key"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("/pathtokeys/1.crt"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("/pathtokeys/2.crt"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("/pathtokeys/3.crt"),
        passprase:"miljul123$$$"
    },
    httpApp).listen(4431);

    // Start Socket.io so it attaches itself to Express server
    var socketServer = io.listen(webServer, {"log level":1});

    var rtc = apsrtc.listen(httpApp, socketServer);
```

Any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you installing the SSL certificates on the Node HTTP server? Would it not be better to install them in Apache then proxy the request?

Comment: @freshnode No it would not be better to use Apache and proxy because its more complicated, slower, and if you were going to use Apache why would you need node?

Comment: @nkumar Did you get the solution? I'm having the same issue